# Android - Make LinearLayout "match_parent" at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got two LinearLayouts, the first as tall as half of the screen, and the second (below it) that should be as tall as the **entire** screen.

**This is the idea:**

```
<LinearLayout ...>
   <LinearLayout id=1>
     ...
   </...>
   <LinearLayout id=2>
     <SlidingTabLayout ...>
     </ ...>
     <ViewPager ...>
     </ ...>
   </ ...>
</ ..>
```

**The second scrolls over the first**, that's why I need the second to be tall as musch as the entire activity.
The problem is that since the second layout is under the first I cannot set its height to *match_parent* in XML and I've got to do it at "runtime". 
I've read lots of posts but nothing worked, any idea ? 
**Thx anticipately !**

**Workaround:** 
As suggested, I measured the height of the firt LinearLayout in the OnResume() and I moved the second programmatically

Comment: You're going to need to write a custom layout for this since it's a special interaction. What you're asking for can't be achieved by standard Android components alone.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent you could try using the PercentRelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout for the parent view

Comment: I think is very similar to the collapsing features introduced with the CoordinatorLayout. In fact when collpasing the toolbar, the layout below, that's usually a scrollview or a RecyclerView, is not simply scrolled, it is moved till it reaches the top, and then the "mock" scrolling is done. But before it reaches the top, it is happening exactly what I'm wondering to do. (Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems to be like this)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
view.setLayoutParams(vp);    // view here is linearLayout with id = 2
```

Comment: Thx @frosty, but the problem is not setting the "match_parent" option itself, but making the LinearLayout being as tall as the Activity.

Comment: How about giving a negative marginTop programmatically?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I didn't succeded in getting the height of the LinearLayouts. I used View.post() and View.getViewTreeObserver(), but with non of them I got the height, it's always 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
   <LinearLayout id=2
    height="some dimension"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     <SlidingTabLayout ...>
     </ ...>
     <ViewPager ...>
     </ ...>
   </ ...>
   <LinearLayout id=1
    height="match_parent"
    above="id=2">
     ...
   </...>
</ ..>
```

Note that the root `LinearLayout` is `RelativeLayout` here.

Side note: Cool pseudocode :)

Comment: Thx for the Side note Man ( @razzledazzle ) :D
However I tried to do what you suggested but it's not working, since the layout that is matching the parent is pushing the layout set above outside the screen. I tried to catch the layout's height so to move the bottom one and make room, but I didn't succed in making it.

Comment: The layout with id 2 must have `android:layout_alignParentBottom` set to `true`. Also, you must supply some static dimension there.

Forgot to add that part so edited that in there.

Comment: Rethought about your issue, better take a look into the Support Design Library, specifically `CoordinatorLayout`.